# JDBC URL while binding data from sqlite database to a jtable

Tags: java, sqlite

What do I feed in the JDBC URL field while binding a database to jtable in NetBeans.
I tried `jdbc:sqlite:school.db` it returns the error:

```
cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlite:school using org.sqlite.JDBC (opening db: 'school': Access is denied)
```

Comment: This depends on your database. Where is it?